# Json.parse return null

Tags: jquery, json

I'm not sure why below return null this is my json string. 
It is cause by the JSON string format?

```
var data = '{"pvd":
            {
            "plannerViewDetailSummary":{"intTargetedCard":6549,"intDeliveredOffer":1,"intRedeemedOffer":1,"dtBegin":"\/Date(1380556800000)\/","dtEnd":"\/Date(1383148800000)\/"},
            "plannerViewDetailChannel":[{"nvarDesc":"Email"}],
            "plannerViewDetailTargetCust":[{"varGroupName":"ALL"}]
            }
    }'

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
if (obj == null) {
    alert('null');
}
```

Comment: is that a valid Json ..?

Comment: When you format the string correctly (ie remove the returns) the code works fine in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/A7aBY/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **line breaks** or escape by a `\` from **json** then try like,

```
var data =  '{"pvd":{"plannerViewDetailSummary":{"intTargetedCard":6549,"intDeliveredOffer":1,"intRedeemedOffer":1,"dtBegin":"\/Date(1380556800000)\/","dtEnd":"\/Date(1383148800000)\/"},"plannerViewDetailChannel":[{"nvarDesc":"Email"}],  "plannerViewDetailTargetCust":[{"varGroupName":"ALL"}]}}';
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
if (obj==null){
   alert('null');
}
console.log(obj);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/LeeUh/)

Answer (score 0):

It's your line breaks in the string that's not valid JSON. Remove them and it will work fine (or escape them with `\`).

Answer (score 0):

here you go..

http://jsfiddle.net/AfnX3/

The issue is in your `data` you cannot have string formatted in such way at least in javascript

```
var data = '{"pvd":{"plannerViewDetailSummary":{"intTargetedCard":6549,"intDeliveredOffer":1,"intRedeemedOffer":2,"dtBegin":"\/Date(1380556800000)\/","dtEnd":"\/Date(1383148800000)\/"},"plannerViewDetailChannel":[{"nvarDesc":"Email"}],"plannerViewDetailTargetCust":[{"varGroupName":"ALL"}]}}'

var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
if (obj == null) {
    alert('null');
} else {
    alert('ok');
}
```